# How to get a list of all named ranges in calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, named-ranges

I want to list out all the named ranges and the data ranges of a Calc workbook containing several sheets. I am jus tmoving from excel to calc and thus not too familiar with functions/macros in calc.

Answer (score 1):

Data ranges are shown by Data→Select Range

Named ranges are shown by Insert→Names→Define

Both types of ranges can also be viewed in the Navigator window (View→Navigator) with named ranges under "Range names" and data ranges under "Database Ranges".